# Effeciently query small read-only data set in python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, heroku

I'm working on a small web service for fetching magic card data.  I'm currently testing things out on Heroku but I'm not tied there - I may just put the whole thing on some EC2 instances and call it a day.

The card data is a single table with 20 columns (colors, casting cost, flavor text, etc) and infrequently changes - a single batch update every three months or so.  For all sets through the most recent update, it's 23mb as a sqlite db, and the most recent update was 228kb.  It's currently ~14k rows and grows around 250 rows every 3 months.

I'm using heroku's postgres but I don't see a reason not to put it in memory given the above, and I imagine it could be appreciably faster.

High startup time isn't out of the question but I'd prefer < 10 minutes.  I thought sqlite + sqlalchemy was the ideal candidate here, but that doesn't seem to work with heroku.  Is that in fact the best option, and I should migrate to ec2 now?  If so, what's the best way to load a sqlite database into memory?

What are the in-memory options for querying read-only data sets in python?

Comment: What's the query pattern? Dynamic search criteria or queries for static views?

Comment: heroku will not support sqlite3 http://railsapps.github.io/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

Comment: dynamic search criteria, and unfortunately there's probably not a strong pattern of common criteria (name or color might be common when looking for a specific card, but then a lot of people do full searches on rules or type/subtype when they're looking for a class of cards.)  **Edit**: one other use will be building a trie of card names for autocompleting.  I don't think that will dictate or even significantly influence the format, however.

Comment: @korylprince: I wish they were a little more specific about "does not support" since I was able (early in development) to load a sqlite database through sqlalchemy, and although my writes weren't persisted, queries were fine.  I assumed this too was fixed, but it's not clear what limit of "not supported" it is.  Does the dependency not get pip installed, or does it not guarantee writes?  The latter is still acceptable for read-only data. (Though, git committing a db just to deploy remains ugly)

Comment: @NumberOverZero Unfortunately I don't have a clue. I've never used heroku.